# How can i do Query filter like this?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to filter the arrays who contains `item.espaco == 'peitoral'`, like this.

My Schema:

```
Mercado.findById({ _id: '5d52e69b4b333234f0bbf1ba' }).where({ 'itens.item.espaco': { $eq: 'peitoral' } }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors or the query executes successfully with empty result?

Comment: the query executes fine, but without filtering, i think my query is wrong, no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mongodb version 3.4 or above 
You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

```
Mercado.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5d52e69b4b333234f0bbf1ba") }},
  { $addFields: {
      itens: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$itens",
          as: "iten",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$iten.item.espaco", "peitoral"] }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

You can use return replacing itens and return filter data using aggregation

Comment: I never used aggregate before, i will learn more about this.. 
Worked very well !! Thank you.